# Having a cell reference its own value in a "loop"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have, on a worksheet, 3 values (`C1`, `C2`, `C3`). `C2` and `C3` are constant and will not change, but I want `C4` to update depending on the value of `C1` (anywhere from 1 to 50).

[image]

Normally I know how to do these things, but I haven't figured this out. Here's what I want to do for this particular case:

I want `C4` to be equal to `C3` plus 2.02% * (`C2`) for every `C1`... meaning that if C1 = 1 then C4 is equal to C3 * 1.0202.

My problem is for higher than 1, I didn't find a way to "recursively" call the cell value, this is what I have so far:

```
=IF( $C$1 = 1; C3; C3 * (1+C2))
```

Obliviously this isn't working and I haven't found a function that'll do what I want. Is there a mathematical way of doing this?

Thanks,

I've tried to make it as clear as possible, don't hesitate to ask me if it's not clear!

EDIT:

Here what the result would look like

```
C1 = 1: 0.625
C1 = 2: 0.625 * 1.0202 = 0.637625
C1 = 3: 0.637625 * 1.0202 = 0.650505025
C1 = 4: 0.650505025 * 1.0202 = 0.663645226505
...
```

I want to use the previous result to calculate the new one

Comment: Are you looking for how to compute [Compound Interest](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141695) (or it's moral equivalent)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using the *power operator* :

`= C3 * (1+C2)^C1`

This multiplies C3 with (1+C2) for C1 times.
This is how compound interest or a growth rate is applied to grow a value.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of `=c3 + c2*c1`?

Nope, you're thinking of `=c3 * (1+c2)^c1` as @peladao posted.

Comment: That's what has been asked for, but I *suspect* asker wants to 'grow' **by** `2.02%` `18` **times**, so he wants `POWER`. Let's see.